# Как добавить в TreeView картинку?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Как к моему примеру вставить любую картинку?

xaml:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree"   TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded"   TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_SelectedItem" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

//здесь происходит привязка //Нужно добавить картинки

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=collection_node}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>


        </TreeView>
```

Но мне нужно чтобы картинка определялась уровнем level моего класса Node.

```
 public class Node
    {
        public string name_ { get; set; }

        public int level { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }


        public Node()
        {
            collection_node = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        }
    }
```

так добавляется объекты Node дерево:

```
tw_tree.ItemsSource = GLOBAL.node.collection_node;
```

Comment: А почему вы создаёте item'ы вручную, а не через HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: потому что не умею. спасибо. посмотрю.

Comment: Исправлено создание item на tw_tree.ItemsSource = GLOBAL.node.collection_node;

Comment: А где картинка в вашем Node? Или откуда вы хотите её брать?

Comment: из папки в программе. В Node её нету.

Comment: Картинка всё время одна и та же?

Comment: Да. Но дальше хочу чтобы к каждому уровню была картинка соответствующая level (разные цвета уровней).

Comment: `Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/tree1.png");`

Comment: Понял, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего, наверное так:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=collection_node}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="30"
               Source="{Binding level, Converter={StaticResource LevelToImageConverter}}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Вам понадобится ещё конвертер, который надо положить в ресурсы страницы (знаете, как?). Сам конвертер выглядит как-то так:

```
public class LevelToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var level = (int)value;
        var uriString = ("pack://application:,,,/Images/tree" + level + ".png";
        return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(uriString));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementaedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException не обработано
Message: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" в PresentationFramework.dll
Дополнительные сведения: "Предоставление значения для "System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "211" и позиция в строке "33".

Comment: `Source="{Binding level, Converter={StaticResource LevelToImageConverter}}"/>`
Не удалось разрешить ресурс LevelToImageConverter

Comment: после добавления заработало `<local:LevelToImageConverter x:Key="LevelToImageConverter"/>`

Comment: @codename0082016: Да, именно так.