# Добавление иконки в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно сделать дерево и чтобы возле каждого элемента была картинка. По сути как здесь, только со своими данными

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача уже упоминалась в этом вопросе  [Как добавить в TreeView картинку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596057/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-treeview-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83) . В целом получилось все, кроме отображения самой картинки.

Создание коллекции.

```
    public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Image Icon { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
        public Node() { Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>(); Id = 0; Icon = new Image(); }

    }
```

Добавление содержимого коллекции

```
Ntree1.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = Name.ToString(), Id = Convert.ToInt32(Id), Icon = sourse_image() })
```

Подгружаю картинку

```
    public static Image sourse_image()
    {
        Image Icon = new Image();
        Uri imageUri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/1.ico", UriKind.Absolute);
        Icon.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
        return Icon;
    }
```

XAML

```
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="30" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Не совсем понимаю почему не отображается картинка в сформированном дереве. Возможно где-то или что-то не так сделал. Прошу указать на мою ошибку и по возможности подсказать примере выполнения.

Comment: А в вашем классе Node свойство Icon имеет тип Image, это что за тип? Из какого пространства имен?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это тип позволяет загружать любые изображение. Находиться в System.Windows.Controls

Comment: Ага, ну понятно почему приведенный код не работает. Image не умеет отображать контролы, он умеет отображать ImageSource, именно такой тип имеет свойство Source у него. Меняйте тип Node.Icon на ImageSource. В https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596057/Как-добавить-в-treeview-картинку на который вы ссылаетесь сделано не так как у вас

Comment: Ну и вообще в модельном классе хранить контролы неправильно в принципе

Answer (score 0):

Посидев почитал разные статьи и просто подумав. Увидел ошибку. У TextBlock нету поддержки такой формы как мне была необходима. Произвел изменения в данном месте, XAML

```
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                    
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Icon="{Binding Icon}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

TextBlock был заменён на MetuItem и отображение информации стало как нужно. Осталось реализовать подставку нужной картинки по условиям и все будет готово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]